# Running multiple ASP.NET Core RC2 Applications on the same port

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, port

I want to be able to run two applications using the same port on the same server. My challenge is both applications have a host file that contains the URL it's listening for on port 80. Usually a web server has the ability to create virtual hosts, but I have no idea what I should be doing in this situation (except googling for a solution).

Comment: You can set this up with IIS(&Kestrel) or WebListener, but Kestrel does not directly support port sharing.

Comment: Have the same issue, ended up using WebListener, works perfectly.

Comment: @pfedotovsky could you provide some details on your WebListener setup? I'm trying to forward http://localhost:8000 to two self hosted .NET Core 1.1 WebAPI services at http://localhost:8001/api/one and http://locahost:8002/api/two, but I'm not quite getting it.

Answer (score 6):

In a production environment you typically want to use a reverse proxy to forward requests to your sites running on Kestrel. You set up your ASP.NET Core applications to run on different ports, i.e. http://example.com:5000 and http://example.com:5001. Then you use IIS, Apache, nginx or similar to act as a reverse proxy. The reverse proxy is listening on port 80 and is forwarding the incoming requests to your Kestrel instances.

Example:

```
http://example.com/app1 --> http://example.com:5000
http://example.com/app2 --> http://example.com:5001
```